# EXC_BAD_ACCESS using << on stringstream object

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I'm writing a code where I need to write a large string into memory.
I used a stringstream object to do so, but something odd to me happens: even if the size of the underlying string buffer has not exceeded the maximum size of a string object my program crashes with a `BAD_ACCESS` error.

I've created a test program like this:

```
#include <sstream> // std::stringstream
#include <iostream> // std::cout

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::stringstream stream;
    std::string string;
    std::cout << "Max string size: " << string.max_size() << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; true; i++) {
        if (i >= 644245094) {
            stream.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
            std::stringstream::pos_type size = stream.tellg();
            stream.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
            std::cout << "Size of stringstream: " << size << "\n";
        }
        stream << "hello";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That `if (i >= 644245094)` inside the loop is only used to print the size of the stringstream buffer just before the program crashes. I've used my debugger to see which was the number of the last iteration and used it to print the size of the buffer just before the crash happens.

This is the output I get:

```
Max string size: 18446744073709551599
Size of stringstream: 3221225470
```

After this the program crashes.

I thought that the cause might be because the program fills up my computer's RAM but the memory used by this program is ~6.01GB so not enough to fill up my RAM. For the record I have a 16GB RAM Macbook Pro.

What could be the problem? Am I missing something about how `<<` operator works?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of a std::stringstream when it gets full and fails may not be consistent across all platforms.

I modified your code and rain it on Yocto 3.19.0-32 64-bit, with gcc 5.4.1. I did not get an exception thrown, rather the stream set one of its failure mode bits.

The code I ran was:

```
#include <sstream>    // std::stringstream
#include <iostream>   // std::cout

std::stringstream::pos_type get_size(std::stringstream& stream)
{
    stream.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::stringstream::pos_type size = stream.tellg();
    stream.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    return size;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    std::string string;
    std::cout << "Max string size: " << string.max_size() << std::endl;
    std::stringstream::pos_type size;

    for (unsigned long i = 0; true; ++i)
    {
        size = get_size(stream);
        stream.write("x", 1);
        if (stream.fail())
        {
            std::cout << "Fail after " << i + 1 << " insertions" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Size of stringstream just before fail: " << size << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    size = get_size(stream);
    std::cout << "Size of stringstream just after fail: " << size << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And I got the following output, which shows that my stringstream filled and failed 56 bytes short of 8GB:

```
Max string size: 4611686018427387897
Fail after 8589934536 insertions
Size of stringstream just before fail: 8589934535
Size of stringstream just after fail: -1
```

Can you not use a different container and pre-allocate the memory, instead of using such a large stringstream?

Comment: Well, for now my workaround has been to print the string directly into an output file without using a stringstream if the size of my instance is too large. What kind of container should I use for this instead of stringstream?

Comment: @jackscorrow If writing direct to file works for you then maybe just go with that. Or, if you know the eventual size in advance, you can start with an empty std::string and call its reserve() member function to preallocate memory, and then append your data to it. That way you get a bad_alloc thrown in advance if there isn't going to be enough memory. You could do the same with a std::vector<char> if you just need a buffer and don't need the value-added string handling functions that std::string offers.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use a string. I would have to change a lot of lines of code and I don't have time for that. Regarding my question I've seen that it's not that I've made a mistake in my code, but it's just how `stringstream` works I guess. I'll see if in the future I'll be able to change the code as you suggested. I'm considering the question answered.